# vbscript taking XML node values and assigning to variables

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am reading in an XML file that contains a set of test results that looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuite>
  <build>
    <run>
      <test>
        <index>1</index>
    <id>1</id>
    <description>Description 1</description>
    <result>Pass</result>
  </test>
  <test>
    <index>2</index>
    <id>2</id>
    <description>Description 2</description>
    <result>Aborted</result>
  </test>
  <test>
    <index>3</index>
    <id>3</id>
    <description>Description 3</description>
    <result>Dependency</result>
  </test>
  <test>
    <index>4</index>
    <id>4</id>
    <description>Description 4</description>
    <result>Failed</result>
  </test>
</run>
</build>
</testsuite>
```

I can succesfully get the  nodes listed by using the following:

```
 strQuery = "/testsuite/build/run/test/ (id|result)"
 Set nodeslist = xmlDoc.selectNodes(strQuery)
```

And I know to use a for each loop to grab the node values...

```
For Each objNode In nodeslist

'WHAT TO DO IN HERE...

Next
```

However, I am now stuck at the point where I need to use the id and its associated result. Essentially I will take this information and upload the result to a test system but at the moment I am stuck on how to loop through the 4 separate test nodes and pick out the id and result for each one, ensuring that they remain linked to each other i.e. if they were to be assigned to variables such as ID and RESULT which I could then perform my upload action on before looping back around and re-assigning them to the values within the next test node.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the comment in

```
  Dim sFSpec : sFSpec    = resolvePath( "..\data\17049535.xml" )
' Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/testsuite/build/run/test/ (id|result)"
' msxml6.dll: NodeTest expected here. /testsuite/build/run/test/ -->(<--id|result)
  Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/testsuite/build/run/test"
  Dim oXDoc  : Set oXDoc = CreateObject( "Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0" )
  oXDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  oXDoc.async = False
  oXDoc.load sFSpec

  If 0 = oXDoc.ParseError Then
     WScript.Echo sFSpec, "looks ok"
     Dim ndlFnd : Set ndlFnd = oXDoc.selectNodes( sXPath )
     If 0 = ndlFnd.length Then
        WScript.Echo "|", sXPath, "| not found"
     Else
        WScript.Echo "found " & ndlFnd.length & " nodes."
        Dim ndTest
        For Each ndTest In ndlFnd
            WScript.Echo ndTest.childNodes(0).tagName, ndTest.childNodes(0).text
            WScript.Echo ndTest.childNodes(1).tagName, ndTest.childNodes(1).text
            WScript.Echo ndTest.selectSingleNode("description").xml
        Next
     End If

  Else
     WScript.Echo oXDoc.ParseError.Reason
  End If
```

I got an error from you XPath query. The output:

```
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\8194209\data\17049535.xml looks ok
found 4 nodes.
index 1
id 1
<description>Description 1</description>
index 2
id 2
<description>Description 2</description>
index 3
id 3
<description>Description 3</description>
index 4
id 4
<description>Description 4</description>
```

from my more orthodox XPath should give you a hint how to deal with a list of your test nodes and their children by either number/position or a 'sub' XPath query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DomDocument")
xmlDoc.Load "testsuite.xml" 

For Each testNode In xmlDoc.selectNodes("/testsuite/build/run/test")

    id = testNode.SelectSingleNode("id").Text
    Wscript.Echo "test/id = " & id

    '// Process something //'

    result = "result"
    testNode.SelectSingleNode("result").Text = result

Next
xmlDoc.Save "testsuite.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression should raise an error, as [Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17049935/1630171) pointed out. Something like this might work, though:

```
...
strQuery = "/testsuite/build/run/test/*[name()='id' or name()='result']"
Set nodeslist = xmlDoc.selectNodes(strQuery)
For i = 0 To nodeslist.Length - 1 Step 2
  WScript.Echo nodeslist(i).text & vbTab & nodeslist(i+1).text
Next
```

Comment: +0.49 - you can't use UBound() on a node collection; you'll have to start with nodeslist.length

Comment: Darn, I *always* make that mistake. Thanks for catching. It's fixed now.